# Save Kannada Characters to server Android Studio PhP

Tags: android, android-studio, post, kannada

I have an android app where, in the form, the user posts kannada text. In the mysql db, i am saving this form contents. However, if i use Google Indic kannada keyboard to input data, it is saving as some junk value for that text field. I have set to utf_general_ci for the mysql field which accepts kannada data, but no help.

Can anyone please suggest how this can be done.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need not do anything special with sqllite in Android. It supports utf8 characters by default. Also please add relevant code to show the flow of reading the data and saving it to sql etc to help debug.

Comment: I am saving this to server using php script, not to the local db